# What is the unit used when storing the depth inside an openEXR file format?

Tags: .exr

I am new to Blender. I have tried searching for an answer to the above question, but haven't found an exact answer to this. The blender version that I am using is 2.92.0.

The task I am trying to achieve is really simple. I want to save the depth of each pixel from the camera. I do not intend to normalize the values and hence have used something as follows using nodes.

[image]

The thing I want to know is what are the units (like meters, cms, mm, etc) that the depths in the openEXR file get stored in?
I have tried to change the values under the "Units" section inside the "scene properties" but that did not have any effect on the values inside the OpenEXR file. I tried opening the file using open cv in python for this.

[image]

Can someone guide me with this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65526/saving-z-data-linearly-accurate-depth-map/65529#65529

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos so am I right in thinking that in case my values in viewing plane are in mm then the values in the openEXR file are in mm as well (Basically should have values only in the range between "Clip Start" and "End")?  If this is the case then can I in any way cross check this?

Comment: Set up a test scene with objects at known pre defined distances, save as HDR then check the pixel values for those areas in some HDT capable editor or image viewer or Blender itself

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I'll try that ..thank you