# Is it possible to obtain float RAW pixel values using the Viewer node?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor

I am going to do **millions** of renderings and want to get around the IO overhead by directly storing the rendering results into Numpy arrays. To store the results into Numpy arrays, I am currently using the Viewer node to access `bpy.data.images['Viewer Node'].pixels` to store the pixel values. For my application, I need to make sure that each pixel value is **NOT** quantized to integers of range [0, 255] and then normalized to [0, 1]. Does anyone know if it is possible to access **RAW** values of each pixel using viewer? Or **suggest** an analysis method so that I asses that myself.

If people here think that it not possible to get the raw values using the Viewer node, then I need to change my rendering pipeline and store the raw data in OpenEXR files.

Also, I noticed that the image in `bpy.data.images['Viewer Node'].pixels` is an RGBA image although I have set `bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.color_mode` to `RGB`. Why is that? I'm afraid the pixel values are also in 8-bit not 16-bit or 32-bit. Is there a way to make find out the number of bits used per pixel?

Comment: Why not render to tiff or openexr?

Comment: @Bruno Because the IO operation quite slow in such scale. Plus, the operating system cannot handle more than a couple of million meta-data files for these many renderings and I have to write another script to deal with that. So it would be ideal if I can find out that I can get the renderings that I want via Viewer node.

Comment: Got it. What about the File Output Node which would give you access to a single file rendering at a time. You would have to read and parse the file format for every frame though...

Comment: I just read the friendly manual. See my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API doc says:

**pixels**

> Image pixels in floating point values
>
> Type: float in [-inf, inf], default 0.0

src: https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_1/bpy.types.Image.html#bpy.types.Image