# Height Map Using Vertex World Height (Z) as RGB Value

Tags: height-map

I am able to render and save a height map from Blender using the nodes:

Render Layers (Out: Depth) > Normalize > ColorRamp (In: Fac, Linear, Out: Image) > Composite (In: Image)

However, the height map treats the lowest point on the mesh as 0 (RGB 0,0,0), and the highest point on the mesh as 1 (RGB 255,255,255). Can I generate the height map using the world coordinates of the vertices instead? My mesh origin is at (0,0,0).

Example - a vertex with a height of 50 should have a height map (RGB) value of (50,50,50).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect the depth output to a viewer node, then open an UV/Image window and select the viewer node as display.

If you click on the image (which seems generally totally white) you can read the values of every pixel.

[image]

So, you can directly save as image using a format that can handle theese "super white" values, like openEXR.

Just remember that Depth pass is not world height but distance from camera, so you will have to add a simple math node, subtracting the Depth value from the Z location of the camera (in my example 5 Blender Units)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Josh! However, I may not have been clear in what I’m looking to do. I am looking to create a regular heightmap with RGB values 0-1.0. However, I’m having an issue where the vertex height doesn’t match the heightmap value. For example, a vertex with a height of 50 seems to lead to a heightmap color of (100,100,100), for some reason. The generated heightmap colors are inconsistent. I would like the heightmap colors to directly match the height of each vertex.

Comment: You can try to put the normalize node after the subtract node, so to map all values between 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: You can read also this interesting answer; https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52328/render-depth-maps-with-world-space-z-distance-with-respect-the-camera/52348#52348